# What is Knowledge Discovery and Data Mining?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, algorithm, data-mining

I suppose SQL queries fetch "raw data"...

Is there any good point to start regarding data mining in SQL server?

Are there any available KDD ready-to-go, algorithms in MS-SQL server 2005, 2008?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there certainly are tons of excellent resources to start with in terms of understanding what's available, how to use it, where to use it, etc. And yes, there are pre-packaged algorithms included with both Sql 2005 and 2008, including:

- [Microsoft Decision Trees](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175312.aspx)
- [Microsoft Naive Bayes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174806.aspx)
- [Microsoft Clustering](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174879.aspx) and [Sequence Clustering](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175462.aspx)
- [Microsoft Neural Network](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174941.aspx)
- [Microsoft Association](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174916.aspx)
- [And more](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175595.aspx)

As well as extensibility support for [3rd party algorithm plug-ins](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176127.aspx).

Excellent resources for starting out with mining in sql server:

- [Sql Server data mining team home](http://www.sqlserverdatamining.com/)
- [Jamie T's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/jamiemac)
- [Data mining on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345131(SQL.90).aspx)
- [Brent Ozar's discussion on mining Stack Overflow](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/06/data-mining-the-stackoverflow-database/)
- And of course [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=data+mining+sql+server)